# Javascript syntax seen in SignalR

Tags: javascript, signalr

When learning the SignalR, I see some JS script pattern like below in the auto-generated hubs script. What's this syntax?

```
(function(a,b,c){...}(e,f));
```

Or in the hubs:

```
(function($, window, undefined){...}(window.jQuery, window));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called a self-executing function.  It basically declares the function code and then calls it immediately passing in the parameters that you see after the function.  In the case of the hubs method it is passing in the window.jQuery object to the '$' parameter, the global window object to the 'window' parameter and omitting the third parameter which will assign a value of 'undefined' to the third parameter.  All of that code is wrapped in a closure.

Using all of the code in a closure typically keeps the code within the closure separate (or private) within the scope of the closure and helps to prevent polluting the global namespace (the window object).

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in JS but I think that with this syntax you define the function and then you call it with the parameters (window.jQuery, window)

Comment: I guess that way, too. I just don't know the official name of this syntax.